# Python replace an index of list separated by split function

Tags: python, list, arraylist, replace, split

I have a long array that looks something like this :

```
arr=["5;V;K;4406632419324152;0123;172;9;0;0;06012020;3000"
"2;M;K;4406553211445698;0123;124;2;0;0;06012020;2000"
"3;M;K;5412115956124218;0123;236;3;0;1;06012020;2000"
"4;V;K;4406621015140546;0123;131;9;0;0;06012020;3000"]
```

Each index is a line from a text file.
The content is not important, what is, however, is that I do not know length of the any index of array (meaning len(arr[i]) would be different for each index, the only way how I can be sure that I am accessing the **"V" or "K"** is by using split function)

```
arr[0].split(";")[1]
```

#### Is there a simple code that would replace the 6th elements (after split) in index to a new value?

What I am trying to achieve is to print

*from*

"5;V;K;4406632419324152;0123;172;**9**;0;0;06012020;3000"

*to*

"5;V;K;4406632419324152;0123;172;**newValue**;0;0;06012020;3000"

Comment: can't you read file as `cvs` file or something similar - ie. using `pandas`?

Comment: well it is unfortunately a highschool group project. We are only "allowed" or "adviced" to use pure tkinter. Even the file has to be a `.txt`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a list comprehension with a ternary operator to replace the 6th element:

```
arr=["5;V;K;4406632419324152;0123;172;9;0;0;06012020;3000",
"2;M;K;4406553211445698;0123;124;2;0;0;06012020;2000",
"3;M;K;5412115956124218;0123;236;3;0;1;06012020;2000",
"4;V;K;4406621015140546;0123;131;9;0;0;06012020;3000"]
new_value = 4
arr[0] = ';'.join(v if i != 6 else str(new_value) for i, v in enumerate(arr[0].split(';')))
print(arr)
```

Output:

```
['5;V;K;4406632419324152;0123;172;4;0;0;06012020;3000', 
 '2;M;K;4406553211445698;0123;124;2;0;0;06012020;2000', 
 '3;M;K;5412115956124218;0123;236;3;0;1;06012020;2000', 
 '4;V;K;4406621015140546;0123;131;9;0;0;06012020;3000'
]
```